# Как пасить ноду биткойна на питоне

Tags: python, bitcoin

Кто знает какие есть варианты получения всех транзакций непосредственно из ноды биткойна по определенному адресу.

У меня есть скрипт который распарсивает данные .dat файлов, но такой расклад не подходит заказчику, я читал в документалке что у ноды битка есть API может есть какой то запрос для решения данной задачи?

Comment: https://github.com/martins87/bitcoin-utxo-server
Только внятно изучайте, я не сразу смог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Биткоин ноды используют низкоуровневый протокол поверх TCP, документация здесь: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation

Но вы можете запросить только целые блоки, отдельно подтвержденные транзакции никто не пересылает:

> getdata is used in response to inv, to retrieve the content of a
> specific object, and is usually sent after receiving an inv packet,
> after filtering known elements. It can be used to retrieve
> transactions, but only if they are in the memory pool or relay set -
> arbitrary access to transactions in the chain is not allowed to avoid
> having clients start to depend on nodes having full transaction
> indexes (which modern nodes do not).

Как это сделать на питоне думайте/ищите сами.

Я когда-то сделал простенькую имплементацию этого протокола на C#: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul.Cryptocurrency/P2P/Peer.cs
Она умела подключатся к ноде, броадкастить транзакцию, и запрашивать блоки.